internet and wifi
i have a problem where it will be connected to wifi, and all of a sudden it will show an ethernet symbol and act like there is no internet although settings say it is connected
and I don't want to have to restart every 5 seconds

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?
